# limit proof in calculus&differential class

Tags: calculus

Can anyone help me to show that

$\lim_{t\to0} u(t,x)$= f(x) 
where u(t,x)=$\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{2 \pi}}$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-y)\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{2\pi kt}}$$ \begin{equation} e^{\frac{-1}{4kt} y^2} \end{equation} dy$

Answer (score 0):

First, it is easy to show that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/(4kt)}}{2\sqrt{\pi kt}}\,dy=1$$

Then, we need only show that

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x-y)-f(x))\frac{e^{-y^2/(4kt)}}{2\sqrt{\pi kt}}\,dy=0$$

Enforcing the substitution $y\mapsto 2\sqrt{kt}y$ reveals

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x-y)-f(x))\frac{e^{-y^2/(4kt)}}{2\sqrt{\pi kt}}\,dy=\frac1{\sqrt \pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x-2\sqrt{kt}y)-f(x))e^{-y^2}\,dy$$

Assuming that $f$ is continuous and bounded, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to0}\frac1{\sqrt \pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x-2\sqrt{kt}y)-f(x))e^{-y^2}\,dy&=\frac1{\sqrt \pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{t\to0}(f(x-2\sqrt{kt}y)-f(x))e^{-y^2}\,dy\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Mike, please let me know how I can improve my answer.   I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.  ;-)